# Identificar o textarea certo para enviar ao pressionar Enter?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu havia "resolvido" um problema de enviar um textarea ao pressionar Enter na minha aplicação, mas acabou que só envia para o primeiro textarea da página.

A aplicação faz um loop de posts registrados no banco de dados e para cada post tem uma área para o usuário comentar. O seguinte código envia o conteudo do primeiro textarea ao pressionar enter:

```
$('#texto_coment').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        this.form.submit();
        return false;
     }
});
```

O que acontece é que na página existem mais de um post e eu não sei como identificar cada um deles.

Formulário para comentar:

```
<form  action="init/add_coment.php" method="post" name="enviaComent">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?=$post['id']?>" name="id_post" />
   <textarea id="texto_coment_<?=$post['id']?>" name="comentario" class="comentario-texto" placeholder="Escreva um comentário..."></textarea> 
</form>
```

Como posso fazer para ao pressionar Enter envie o comentário em um textarea especifico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o javascript esta referenciando o textarea `#texto_coment`, mas no textarea o id é outro `texto_coment_<?=$post['id']?>`

A solução é fazer o javascript referenciar o textarea corretamente, como você tem mais de um textarea é interessante fazer isso pela classe, assim um javascript funciona para todos.

Usando a classe:

```
$('.comentario-texto').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        this.form.submit();
        return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, Marcos!

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
<form  action="init/add_coment.php" method="post" id="enviaComent<?=$post['id']?>">
<textarea  name="comentario" class="comentario-texto" placeholder="Escreva um comentário..." onkeypress="javascript:submeterTextArea(event.keyCode,<?=$post['id']?>);"></textarea>
```

Na sua *textArea* não é necessário ter um id, mas será necessário um form para cada *textArea*, pois você quer submeter apenas o *form* que pressionou *Enter*.

Dentro do javascript você faz a função:

```
function submeterTextArea(ev,id){
    if(ev==13){
       $('#enviaComent'+id).submit();
    }
}
```

O segredo dessa solução é informar o **id** como argumento da função javascript, assim você terá a "pista" necessária de qual form submeter dentro do *script*.

Uma alternativa a ter vários *forms* na mesma página seria fazer o envio por *ajax*, sem utilizar um **form.submit()**, isso seria útil caso a página de aterrizagem pós inserção do comentário fosse a mesma página já com o novo comentário.

Essa segunda abordagem além de economizar o ***refresh*** na página demanda menos conexão, e é mais elegante pois não rola a página no navegador do usuário.

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, eu irei implementar isso sim!